# How to compute flux through a sphere when flux density is given in rectangular co-ordinates?

Tags: physics

[image]

Compute the total flux of **D** leaving a sphere of radius 1m, and hence the total charge enclosed by that sphere. **D**(x,y,z) = x**X̂**

Attached is my current working and the worked solutions provided to us. The only issue is that I don't understand the worked solution and I don't understand what I have done wrong in my working. However, I don't have a great understanding of electromagnetics yet so I am not surprised that it is wrong.

[Worked solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf7iN.png)[image: My working]

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue in the second line: **x** is not equal to **r**. You can use the rotation matrix to work out what it should be:

[image]

However, this gets very messy but is doable. Most of the worked answer is using the fact that r=1 to get around this complication.